# svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted | Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, subversion

When we use svn to push files from local or remote server to svn end or delete files, we may meet a problem about "cannot remove Device or resource busy". The reason is that we didn't do svn commit and svn update after doing one svn add or svn delete, then we did another svn add or svn delete.

On this condition, svn cleanup may not solve this problem as well.

So how should we solve this problem.

Comment: If you get E155037, that means that you were probably in the middle of an `svn commit` or `svn update` at some point but it got interrupted part-way through.  It doesn't have anything to do with `svn add` or `svn delete`.   Does `svn cleanup` output anything?  If you use `svn:externals`, then `svn cleanup --include-externals` may be the missing part.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by killing sessions that run those nfs0000* files.

Input code
`lsof |grep nfs000000000b0c04750000001f`
Here nfs000000000b0c04750000001f is your nfs file name. Yours may be different.

Then you will see something like this.
less  22081  xxxx    4r      REG     0,43      7834  185336964 
less  25122  xxxx    4r      REG     0,43      7834  185336964

Here the 2nd column contains the session ID, which is 22081 or 25122.

Next, we kill these sessions.
`kill -9 Session_ID(2nd column)`

After killing session, we run `svn cleanup`, then `svn commit -m "blabla"`.